Tint colour will not apply to sidebar of NavigationSplitView
My accent color (which is set to red) will not apply to the sidebar of my NavigationSplitView. So, I tried explicitly setting the tint color to red, and still it does not work. I did try setting other items (such as the foregroundColor of Text) to red or accent, and that worked properly. It is just the sidebar which will not conform.
Does anyone know what could possibly be causing this? I am just learning swift (this is my first project) so please explain things well.
The relevant part of the code:
NavigationSplitView {
            // Defining the sidebar items by looping throuhg each item in sidebar array
            List(selection: $selectedPage) {
                ForEach(Array(sidebar), id: \.self) { option in
                    NavigationLink(value: option.name) {
                        Image(systemName: option.img)
                        Text(option.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear{selectedPage = "Changelogs"} // Set the default page
            .tint(.red) //  Setting tint to red, but the tint is not applying!
        }
        detail: { ... }

Here is the result, which is still using the default blue tint.

I have accent colour set to "Multicolour" in system preferences, so no conflict happening there.

EDIT: I should clarify, my AccentColor in my Assets.xcassets is set to red, but the sidebar stays blue regardless.

You should change the "AccentColor" in your asset catalog to your desired color.

I have changed the accent color, but it remains blue

What version of macOS are you running? This works for me on macOS 14.5.

I don't want to use an accent colour, because then my NSMenuItem is highlighted orange improperly as well. Is there a way to only use light effect like in the Music app?
